# One word an act in which one is lying and another joins in to make it sound true

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I was bluffing my sister about something and my friend just played along and proved whatever I was saying true. 
Is there a word to define play along?

Comment: Please add an example sentence that the word would be used in.

Comment: What is wrong with *play along*? It fits fine, it is a word, and you've just used it yourself. A perfect match.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly tongue-in-cheek sense of **abet** is reasonable here:

> *abet*
>
> v.t.  to encourage, support, or countenance by aid or approval, usu.
>   in wrongdoing.
>
> Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010

At [APLS](https://polarisweb.arlingtonlibrary.org/Mobile/BakerAndTaylor/Review?ISBN=0439828627&UPC=&position=1)

we find such a tongue-in-cheek (encouraging in mischief rather than evil) usage:

Kirkus Reviews

> Funke and Meyer deliver a third collaboration featuring a feisty,
>   imaginative kid. This time, it's Ben (mostly tolerated and
>   occasionally abetted by his older sister Anna), whose powerful
>   fantasies fuel his raucous play. Whether he's a wolf, knight, monster
>   or himself ...

Answer (score 0):

*Collude*/*Conspire* might work. They mean to work together against another group/individual, although they usually have negative connotations (not sure if that matters to you).